# MySQL: Set Default Collation Connection and MySQL Dump

Tags: mysql, collation

I am running MySQL 5.5.20 on Windows Vista Business. I am having a bit of a problem with collation_connection. My default charset is utf8 and collation is ut8_unicode_ci. However, when I perform mysql dumps on the database, my functions and procedures have the collation_connection showing utf8_general_ci; for example,

```
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci*/ ;
```

Is it possible to specify MySQL to default to ut8_unicode_ci for collation_connection? I use MySQL Workbench to perform the mysql dumps.

Comment: did you set general collaction on database table?

Comment: why do you consider it important? Collation is important when you compare strings, that is important is the collation of table fields. For connections only the charset makes sense.

Comment: Database tables are set to ut8_unicode_ci collation. As to considering important, I wasn't necessarily thinking if it was important or not, rather wondering if it was something to be concerned with, or could I just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

*Nowadays consider using utf8mb4 instead of utf8.*

If you want the behavior you're describing, you first would execute:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Then redefine affected functions, procedures and triggers.

Next time you execute mysqldump, generated file will have lines like this:

```
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8mb4_unicode_ci*/ ;
```

More details about `SET NAMES` in [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-names.html).